# Looking for a grid template for PowerPoint

Tags: page-layout, presentation-design, microsoft-powerpoint, grids

I'm new to this community. I wouldn't describe myself so much as a designer but rather someone who has a need to create presentations as part of my job and would like to improve the design of those presentations.

I've recently discovered grids and would like to begin experimenting with them. All my work is done in PowerPoint, but I've not been able to locate a grid template I could use in PowerPoint. Using the Guides in PP is hugely frustrating since you can't lock them, so I'm constantly grabbing them by accident.

So, I'm looking for something like a .pptx file where the gridlines are part of the Master slide that I could turn off when finished designing.

Does anyone know where such templates can be found?

Comment: +1 just for trying to make a PPT presentation less sucky. On behalf of everyone who's ever had to sit through one... thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Wearing my hazmat suit today, so I'll give this one a shot. ;-)

I don't know of any such templates, but you may find something worthwhile on the MS Office website.

Your best best, I'd say, would be to:

- Set up a temporary background on the master slide with your grid indicated in light gray or blue. You could do this with a transparent png, I expect, over the actual slide background.
- Turn *off* "Snap to Grid," drag out your guides to match the template slide, then turn off the visibility of the actual guides so you can't accidentally move them. Your artwork will snap to them even when they're not visible.
- When you're done, remove the temporary guide image from the master slide(s).

Most folks here love using Powerpoint about as much as we love cuddling cobras.

Answer (score 1):

You can design grids with guides in the master layout. They are 'locked' when working in standard layout mode. You can turn them off by deselecting **Guides** in the context menu.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a similar thing and found this post very helpful.
https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/advanced-powerpoint-grids-guides/

Comment: Hello Maayan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. We're weary of link-only answers, since links tend to rot over time, and then the answer becomes useless. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer to include the most important parts of the linked content? Also, might I suggest taking the [tour] and maybe read the [help] to get a better feel for our site. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!